# Messages being lost on consumer falling over

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

This seems like a pretty basic question, but I seem to be losing messages when the consumer falls over before acknowledging them. I have set up the broker with an exchange audit:exchange and a queue bound to it audti:queue. Both are durable, and as expected if I send messages when no consumer is active they sit on the queue and get processed by the consumer when it starts up. However if I put a break point in the consumer and kill the process half way through, the message is not requeued - it just seems to get lost. The consumer is set up using the annotation

```
@RabbitListener(queues="audit:queue")
public void process(Message message) {
    routeMessage(message)  //stop here and kill process - message removed from q
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue.

With the breakpoint triggered, I see the message still in the queue (unacked=1) on the rabbit console.

When the process is killed; the message goes back to ready.

Have you configured the listener container factory to use `Acknowledgemode.NONE`?

That will exhibit the behavior you describe.

The default is `AUTO` which means the message will only be acknowledged when the listener returns successfully.

If you still think there's an issue; please supply the complete test case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have mentioned I seem to be using spring-rabbit 1.4.5 if this is relevant. Also I did check the rabbit doc which mentioned in the Reliable Delivery section: "If a message is delivered to a consumer and then requeued (**because it was not acknowledged before the consumer connection dropped, for example**) ... " which is the behaviour I was expecting.

Comment: I will try to put together a simple example .. difficult as our work machies are not connected to internet and I am not allowed to mail code to myself, but I will try to do this over the weekend.

Comment: Damn I keep hitting enter and the comment gets posted. I am definitely using acks - when a message is being processed  I see the unacked count go up to 1 (and the ready count go to 0) in the admin console. Then after killing the consumer, after a couple of secinds the unacked count goes down to 0, and the ready count is still 0. If my cnsumer throws an exceotn the expected behaviour is seen - the message goes back on the queue and gets redelivered

Comment: As I said; I have a simple test case and I simply don't see the behavior you are seeing; when I kill the java task, the message goes back to ready. Are you sure you don't have some other consumer running someplace that's getting the message? (Trust me; I have encountered such a situation before and it drove me nuts). You can see a list of consumers on the queue's page on the management console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was my bad (I just wasted a few hours .. sigh). I was killing the app from within my ide. Which probably detaches and then kills the process - allowing time for it to proceed just enough that it actually does send the ack. When I just killed the process from a terminal it worked exactly as expected. Particualr apologies to you Gary for wasting your time as well.